# How can I combine Google Maps and an Infobox based on a Backbone View

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js, google-maps-markers

I would like to have a google map, that when a marker is clicked, will open a Info box (or custom overlay) that is in fact (or based on)  a Backbone View. The backbone view should get it's content by placing an ajax call when it is first opened, but if closed and re-open should not make another call to the server (should display the result from the first opening)

I simply have no idea how to implement this since the info box's content is a dom element (which i want to change/populate only when it is opened for the first time). (btw i'm mainly a backend developer, front-end is very new to me)

What I was think of is doing something similar to this, but I'm not sure this is the right way to go:

```
var view = new MyOverlayBackboneView({ model: myModel});
var infoBoxOptions = {
   content: view.el
};



var infoBox = new InfoBox(infoBoxOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(some_lat, some_lng),
    ...
    other marker related parameters
});

marker.infoBox = infoBox;

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    this.infoBox.open(map, this);
}
```

What I lack here, and am a little clue less as where to perform, is the render() part of the Backbone View the first time the infobox is opened.

Needless to say, I want the part of code that initiates the infobox to be as clean as possible, and leave any styling and ajax calls to the backbone view.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction (tutorial / sample code).
Thanks in advance for any help you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Your view could be something like this:

```
MyOverlayBackboneView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    [rendering the contents of your view here]
    return this;
  }
};
```

And then when creating your Info Box:

```
var infoBoxOptions = {
  content: view.render().el
};
```

This would have your view render only once and then put the contents that were rendered into the InfoBox.

Comment: but where will the View fetch the its collection from the server? If I put it in render() it means that all infoBoxes will fetch from the server upon creation, and not upon opening. that means i'm fetching data from the server that might never be seen. I want the ajax call to be made only when the infoBox is open (and the Backbone view is made visible)

Comment: That solved it for me. Ty!  @ken you can send the actually data over a socket. You just send the template for the client.. I dunno if there's a way to send the template over socket/ajax, but you can send the content that way.. I dunno about ajax, but socket.io is pretty descent.